# Error installing ubuntu-desktop depdendencies

Tags: 16.04, apt

I'm trying to install ubuntu-desktop on my ubuntu server, but every time I try to install I get depdendecy errors.

Every time I try to install the package it says it needs it just goes deeper and deeper.  Ive tried `clean`, `autoremove`, `clear cache`, `dist-upgrade`, etc all of the recommendations online but none of them are working.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: checkbox-gui but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Edit:

I'm logged in as the root user.

Command I was using to install: `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Commands I tried to fix it:

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: what is the exact command that you are using?

Comment: @ravery I added it into my post.

Comment: `apt-get -f install` will fix missing dependencies

Comment: @ravery Forgot to add that I tried that too and it didn't install anything.

Comment: If you have `aptitude` installed, it will resolve the dependency tree and install all needed packages if they are available.

Comment: @cclloyd excuse me did you solve the problem ?

Comment: @Sam I managed to install aptitude and it resolved dependencies for me.  Not sure if I ever resolved the dependency issue with `apt` on this VM though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after trying out KDE plasma and removing it without purging the ppa but the solution was to reconfigure lightdm with

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Also, make sure you have installed `lightdm` and the `ubuntu-unity-desktop`